# "Unable to step. Process is not synchronized" error in VS2010 after upgrading .NET Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I had Visual Studio 2010 installed on my Windows 7 desktop, that I was using primarily to debug ASP.NET solutions. Everything was working great, until one of the Windows updates installed a new version of the .NET Framework. Now I get the following message when I try to place a breakpoint and then do a "debugger step" in my C# code:

[image]

To make matters worse, it doesn't happen all the time. I tried to find any pattern, but the best way I can describe it is sporadic.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @ForeverWintr: You know, it somehow got resolved... I'm trying to think what did I do differently. It might've been that rebooting computer helped... I'll post an update if I remember.

Comment: Interesting. It went away for me too, and I'm not sure what I did. I may have rebooted too.

Comment: @ForeverWintr: As I come to think about it, I might have killed the w3wp.exe process and restarted the VS. Another option would be to restart the web site in the IIS manager.

Comment: This actually happens to me not in asp.net, but while debugging an excel add-in. I'm guessing this is a bug in VS 2010. Restarting seems to make it go away temporarily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just got this in Visual Studio 2015.  I was debugging on a separate thread, hit the breakpoint but could not continue.  A reboot did not fix it.

I deleted all of my breakpoints, reset the two that I actually wanted and it works!

Comment: Visual Studio is so broke.  Getting this in VS 2017, latest release, too.  First, while stepping, it freezes with a message about 'evaluating local variables', on a really simple line of code.  When it recovers and I try to step again, the whole thing crashes with this "Unable to step. Process not synchronized.' error.

Comment: Exactly the same for me - VS2017 - I've been trying to debug some code for the last hour!  Tried resetting IIS (it's a web app), restarted machine numerous times.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, usually when I'm stepping through code whilst debugging unit tests. VS2017CE 15.5.2. It's disconcerting that this issue is almost 5 years old.

Comment: Woohoo! Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you try using the resharper test runner.  I have also been hitting this error a lot in VS2017 15.5.2 I have found its something to do with the VS test system.

Even though this solution is a product recommendation (I don't work there) it solved my issue and I was able to get things debugged.